# Set an image in imageView

Tags: android, imageview

I'm pretty new in Android and I am trying to make a Mancala (it's kind of an African game) app. I am looking for a way to update an Image View from one image to another programmatically (for those who are familiar with the game- I want the images of the empty holes to update to images with balls every time the player plays).

I tried to look for an answer but I didn't find one. Here is what I've tried:

```
imgHome2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.home0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in findViewById you should pass an id not a drawable

```
 imgHome2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimageviewid)
```

and than you can change the image by

```
 imgHome2.setBackground(R.drawable.home0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do same by using **Drawable**:

```
private ImageView imageView;
```

on **onCreate()**

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
```

Create new method for set drawable on ImageView.

```
private void setDrawableOnImageView(Drawable drawable){
    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

How to call above method:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);    
setDrawableOnImageView(drawable);
```

You can change drawable as your requirement.

Comment: @nitz123, Can you please accept answer ? If you are happy with answer . ;)

Comment: Sure ,I am just a little new here  :)

Comment: @nitz123, you have to do Tick mark on answer. As you did has19 answer. Thanks :)